# Ruby on Rails: How can I create a scope that checks whether there is an attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have a movie object with a "poster" attachment through active storage (has_one_attached :poster)

I would like to create a scope to retrieve all movies that do not have a poster attached, however this here does not work:

```
scope :no_poster, -> { where (poster: nil) }
```

It results in an error saying

```
Unknown column 'movies.poster' in 'where clause'
```

(which sort of makes sense to me :)

How do I create such a scope?

Comment: Can you please add which rails version are you using?

Comment: Sure - using version 6.1.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just answering my own question here if ever somebody searches for this: engineersmnky's comment is spot on, the relationship name IS poster_attachment, so in order to create a scope that searches for movies without a poster is

```
scope :no_poster, -> { where.missing(:poster_attachment) }
```

Answer (score -1):

Rails 6.1 [adds](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34727) a query method missing to search for orphan records within ActiveRecord.

Try

```
scope :no_poster, -> { where.missing(:poster_attachment) }
```

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately. I think it has to do with the fact that poster isn't really a field in the model... it's an attachment coming from active storage.... so hence I understand why it says "unknown column"...

Comment: @tkhobbes try changing this to `scope :no_poster, -> { where.missing(:poster_attachment) }` since that is the actual relationship name created by the `has_one_attached` macro.